# read/write file, internal storage (android studio-java)

Tags: java, android, internal-storage

i have a folder on Internal Storage on the path  ***"/data/data/1/"*** , my phone is   ***root***  and i have SuperUser and  ***i can see and edit it with phone`s file manager*** , but I don't have permissions to access this file from my app , my code :

```
try {
            java.lang.Process p0 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "root" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
catch(Exception e){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not root" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

            File root0 = new File("/data/data/1/");
            File dir = new File(root0.getAbsolutePath());

if (dir.exists()){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if (dir.canRead()){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "read" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not read", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
if (dir.canWrite()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "write", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not write", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
}catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```

when i run, the app say :  ***root,exist,not read,not write***, Please tell how can I can get this folder to read/write ?

Comment: What is the meaning of want to put a file there?  Can your application only be used by those who have the phone rooted?

Comment: @Tonteria24 , i have files in this folder and can edit this folder and files from "phone`s file manager" , but i don`t have permission from my app to write/read them , yes my app is only for rooted phone, please help me , thnx